# Tyring to create a SQL statement to update a data row

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

Trying to do an update statement in VBA

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Termination] SET [Division] ='" & Division & "' WHERE [Emp ID] = '" & EmpID & "' AND [Key ID] = '" & KeyID & "'"
```

The above creates this

```
"UPDATE [Termination] SET [Division] ='24' WHERE [Emp ID] = 'JD50' AND [Key ID] = '1010264890'"
```

When is runs I get

> Runtime error 3061 - too few parameters. Expected 1.

Help appreciated.

Thanks!